# Mysql database python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I'm trying to import csv format into mysql using Spyder, then from the sql data to plot a graph using pandas (this is a work project).

This is my code:

```
import mysql.connector,sys, pandas as pd

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

df = pd.read_csv("Temperature.csv")

user,pw, host,db = 'user', '123','localhost','xyz'


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pw, host=host, database=db,use_pure=True)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
for index, col in df.iterrows():

    data = {
       'year': col[0],
       'mean': col[1],
       'minimum': col[2],
       'maximum': col[3]

     }

### Make sure the code below is indented inside the for loop
    query = insert_stmt = ("INSERT INTO Temperature(year,mean, minimum, maximum)"
                            "VALUES (%(year)f, %(mean)f, %(minimum)f, %(maximum)f")

    cursor.execute(query, data) 
    print("Adding row " + str(index))
    cnx.commit() # Make sure data is committed to the database

    query1 = "SELECT * FROM rh_means_daily"
    cursor.execute(query)
```

However I had encountered an error message:

```
ProgrammingError: Failed processing pyformat-parameters; Python 'float64' cannot be converted to a MySQL type
```

May I know which part went wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, there could be a problem with the data you're extracting being a Numpy64 data type. To cure this at the point that data is entered into your dictionary, do this to convert it to a normal Python float:

```
data = {
   'year': col[0],
   'mean': float(col[1]),
   'minimum': float(col[2]),
   'maximum': float(col[3])
 }
```

Then, you must always use %s for dictionary fields, so above should be:

```
insert_stmt = ("INSERT INTO Temperature(year,mean, minimum, maximum) VALUES (%(year)s, %(mean)s, %(minimum)s, %(maximum)s)")
```

See official document here for more details: https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.execute

Comment: where should I place this code at? I tried to place after 'data', and after 'query', it said it's not found.

Comment: Ok - first up - where is your connection? You haven't made a mysql connection in your above code, so even if everything else was correct, you would get an error.

Comment: I had updated my code. It's above the 'for loop' that I didn't copy it.

Comment: So from looking into this - the format string is not really a normal Python format string. You must always use %s for dictionary fields, so above should be "INSERT INTO Temperature(year,mean, minimum, maximum)"
                            "VALUES (%(year)s, %(mean)s, %(minimum)s, %(maximum)s")

Comment: yes, I tried s instead as you mentioned, but I still had the same error that float64 cannot be converted. You mentioned previously that it cannot convert numpy float right? How do I convert it back to python float?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207348/discussion-between-hayden-eastwood-and-user12550148).

Comment: ok, try this:    data = {
       'year': col[0],
       'mean': float(col[1]),
       'minimum': float(col[2]),
       'maximum': float(col[3])
     }

Comment: Thanks, there's no error messages from this code. However when I tried to query the 'mean', it state it cannot be found. Error message: Table 'mydatabase.mean' doesn't exist. I tried to open mysql workbench, nothing is reflected there too.

Comment: When I tried to execute the command, it had this error: ' AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode''

Comment: I have moved this to private chat